# Fragment paused inside a ViewPager doesn't receive LiveData events

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

It's the second project that I am facing this problem, and I really can't find a good solution anywhere in the internet. I hope I can make myself clear.

The fragment doesn't receive the event when paused (which is fine) but it also doesn't receive when coming back to resume, a change made from another fragment for example, doesn't doesn't reflect in this one, until you make another change to the livedata (when it's resumed).

Here's my code in case it has a bug:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(FavoritesViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getFavoritedItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        val list = mutableListOf<DBMovie>()    // These lines copies the list as I don't want
        list.addAll(it)                        // to pass it "by reference". But you can ignore it
        favoritesAdapter.submitList(list)
    })
}
```

In the past I have called something like `viewmodel.reloadData()` on the fragment's `onResume()`, but I feel like it's a dirty solution, and I want to do it the right way. Maybe I have to extend `LiveData` and make it notify changes when coming back from paused. Did anybody have this problem?

Comment: Because you should be scoping it to the shared parent fragment and not to this instance of the fragment

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you! I believe the parent fragment would be the AppCompatActivity, right? But I am getting null from parentFragment...

Comment: Right, I tried scoping the viewmodel with requireActivity(), and the livedata with viewLifecycleOwner. Didn't work either.

Comment: Then it depends on how the other call-site scopes `FavoritesViewModel` because it should work

Comment: This fragment is the only one using this viewmodel. The change in the livedata is made by a repository, and it's being observed only by this fragment, every other parts just return the livedata one to another